# Rails peperclip - help crop the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

Welcome, help crop the image,

> has_attached_file: image, styles: {show: '540x505 #'}

trims as needed, but is centered on the (up), I need to image is not centralized, and trimmed the top

**Original image:**

[image]

**Need:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the [-gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) option to **North** when defining paperclip's style. Something like...

```rb
has_attached_file: image, 
    styles: {show: '540x505'},
    convert_options: {show: ' -gravity North '}
```

See documents & example usage [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { show: '' },
                convert_options: {show: '-gravity north -thumbnail 540x505^ -extent 540x505' }
```